# Basic authentication. one user for each website on the server

Tags: iis-7, basic-authentication

I have deployed 2 websites on a server (windows Server 2008 R2 Standard).

I want to use a Basic windows authentication for them

For that I enabled Basic Authentication in the IIS Manager.

I have created 2 users one for each site.

How can I make that only **User1** can access **website1** and **user2** can access **website2**

Currently both users can access both websites. I just want 1 user for each

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add/Edit an "Authorisation rule" for each website to Allow only the specific user you want the access given to.